Only Display Posts after a WooCommerce Product Purchase date
I would like to display ONLY posts from a custom post type that have been published AFTER the purchase date, of product ID 2642, for the currently logged in customer.
I am using WooCommerce Memberships (By SkyVerge) plugin for restricting page access and Elementor for the page builder.
Update:
I found Get user last purchase date from specific product in WooCommerce answer code as a possible way to get the purchase date.

You can use one of these answer code functions, to get the last purchase date for your product ID 2642. Then you can use that purchase date in pre_get_posts action hook, for your custom post type, to display ONLY posts from that purchase date.
